# html div is not responding correctly

Tags: html, css

i am having trouble with my new project. i code corectly if i say.

[image]

[link of the website- which is having problem](http://www.j-lou.info/fashion-directory/index.php)

This div is giving me tension

```
<div class="content-bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. The content looks right in IE8 and Chrome on my windows XP.

Comment: As aside note I'd suggest you to avoid using empty markup for graphic-only purpose. You could replace it by adding that background to an outer element or in some `:after` psudoelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

After checking your code, I noticed that you understand the theory of floating and clearing, so I checked a bit more... It seems that you have **unclosed `</div>` somewhere**, thus rendering yout `div.content-bottom` on a different DOM level then after the `div.content-middle`.

#### Original answer:

It's because of the floating on your `#content` and `#sidebar`

You should use `clear:both;` for the `.content-bottom` div.

Read more about clearing and floating here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: i tried, and it working, but if you see again .. at the end its not showing properly on just homepage

Comment: i double check but there is no any ''unclosed </div>

Comment: it also might be any other unclosed element.

Comment: @Muzammil: You **do** have an unclosed `<div>` element somewhere. The W3C validator seems to think it is your `div#inner-wrapper` and/or `div#wrap` elements, but honestly I don't feel like looking through your entire source to see if it's correct.

Comment: @AdamKiss I check my codes and re-verify and linedup now the problem is resolved on home pages .. but now another problem comes up on other pages .. can you please check

Comment: Validator says: "Line 336, Column 7: end tag for "fieldset" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified" – Check all your fieldsets

Answer (score 1):

It goes wrong because you float the other elements within `<div class="block`>`

Set the css property `clear: both;` on the class `content-bottom` and it should work.

Comment: I updated my answer with what would fix it. Apparantly Adam Kiss has found something else you might want to fix.

Answer (score -1):

Just give float: left to .content-bottom class and it will solve your problem..

Comment: Instead of clear giving float is NOT a good suggestion at all

Comment: For which reason float is not advisable? Please ignor my english... 
Cause I have use that in many of my projects and works fine for all time for me..